# Adding auto-ads with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, adsense

I have tried to add auto-ads to my website which uses Vue.js but there are no requests via the script.

I have tried the vue-adsense plugin, which can be found on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-adsense

but they have no support for auto-ads, normal ads work fine with this plugin.

This is the code which needs to be added:

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-0990618353003742" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Is there a solution for adding auto-ads on a vue.js site?

Answer (score 1):

You can init your ads how many you've added after change data. For example.

```
data() {
    return {
        ads: {
            main: "adhtml",
            between: "adhtml"
        }
    }
},
mounted: function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.ads).length; i++) {
        console.log('vue ad ' + i + ' inited');
        (adsybygoogle = window.adsybygoogle || []).push({});
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Script tags cannot be placed in a part of the DOM controlled by an instance of `Vue()`. All you need to do is place the script in the `<head>` of your document. If you are using Vue CLI to create your project, the file you do this in is `/public/index.html`.